# How to normalize a nested json with json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe out of a nested json. For some reason, I seem to be unable to address the third level.

My json looks something like this:

```
  "numberOfResults": 376,
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "single",
      "docs": [
        {
          "id": "RAKDI342342",
          "type": "Culture",
          "category": "Culture",
          "media": "unknown",
          "label": "exampellabel",
          "title": "testtitle and titletest",
          "subtitle": "Archive" 

            ]
        },
        {
          "id": "GUI6N5QHBPTO6GJ66VP5OXB7GKX6J7ER",
          "type": "Culture",
          "category": "Culture",
          "media": "image",
          "label": "more label als example",
          "title": "test the second title",
          "subtitle": "picture"
```

and so on.

Within the "docs"-part are all the actual results, starting with "id". Once all the information is there, the next block starting with "id" simply follows.

Now I am trying to create a table with the keys id, label and title (for a start) for each of these separate blocks (in this case actual items).

After defining the search_url (where I get the json from), my code for this currently looks like this:

```
result = requests.get(search_url)
data = result.json()
data.keys()
```

With this, I get told that they dict_keys are the following:

```
dict_keys(['numberOfResults', 'results', 'facets', 'entities', 'fulltexts', 'correctedQuery', 'highlightedTerms', 'randomSeed', 'nextCursorMark'])
```

Given the json from above, I know I want to look into "results" and then further into "docs". According to the documentation I found, I should be able to achieve this by addressing the results-part directly and then addressing the nested bit by separating the fields with ".".
I have now tried the following the code:

```
fields = ["docs.id", "docs.label", "docs.title"]
df = pd.json_normalize(data["results"])
df[fields]
```

This works until df[field] - at this stage the programm tells me:

```
KeyError: "['docs.id'] not in index"
```

It does work for the level above though, so if I try the same with "name" and "docs" I get a lovely dataframe. What am I doing wrong? I am still a python and pandas beginner and would appreciate any help very much!

EDIT:

The desired dataframe output would look roughly like this:

```
    id              label            title  
0   RAKDI342342     exampellabel     testtitle and titletest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)
- The following code uses `pandas v.1.2.4`
- If you don't want the other columns, remove the list of `keys` assigned to `meta`
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove any other unwanted columns from `df`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['results', 'docs'], meta=[['results', 'name'], 'numberOfResults'])

display(df)
                                 id     type category    media                   label                    title subtitle results.name numberOfResults
0                       RAKDI342342  Culture  Culture  unknown            exampellabel  testtitle and titletest  Archive       single             376
1  GUI6N5QHBPTO6GJ66VP5OXB7GKX6J7ER  Culture  Culture    image  more label als example    test the second title  picture       single             376
```

### Data

- The posted JSON / Dict is not correctly formed
- Assuming the following corrected form

```json
data = \
{'numberOfResults': 376,
 'results': [{'docs': [{'category': 'Culture',
                        'id': 'RAKDI342342',
                        'label': 'exampellabel',
                        'media': 'unknown',
                        'subtitle': 'Archive',
                        'title': 'testtitle and titletest',
                        'type': 'Culture'},
                       {'category': 'Culture',
                        'id': 'GUI6N5QHBPTO6GJ66VP5OXB7GKX6J7ER',
                        'label': 'more label als example',
                        'media': 'image',
                        'subtitle': 'picture',
                        'title': 'test the second title',
                        'type': 'Culture'}],
              'name': 'single'}]}
```